# How to select a custom .jscsrc file

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter, jscs

We have multiple projects with various `.jscsrc` files.
I'd like to use one that I defined, which is stricter than most projects.

In my case its `~/.jscsrc`.

How can I configure `sublime-linter` to use that file for `jscs`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SublimeLinter is executing `jscs` on your system.  To define the path to the config file ([according to the docs](http://jscs.info/overview.html#-config-c)) for `jscs` using the CLI, you'd run:

`jscs path[ path[...]] --config=~/.config.json`

To set this for the SublimeLinter package you can use [SublimeLinter's `args` setting](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/linter_settings.html?highlight=args#args) for `jscs` and set the config path.  This would be in your `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` (default or user):

```
{
    "user": {
        "linters": {
            "jscs": {
                "args": [
                    "--config=~/.jscsrc"
                ]
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Or alternatively, you can just use `"args": "--config=~/.jscsrc"`.

Note, [from the docs](http://jscs.info/overview.html#-config-c):

> If there is no `--config` option specified, `jscs` it will consequentially search for `jscsConfig` option in `package.json` file then for `.jscsrc` (which is a just JSON with comments) and `.jscs.json` files in the current working directory then in nearest ancestor until it hits the system root.

Also, the path to the `.jscsrc` file is cached, so if you create a new `.jscsrc` that should have precedence over the previous one (according to the above), you need to clear the cache for the linter to use the new `.jcscrc` You can clear the cache by going to: `Tools > SublimeLinter > Clear Caches`.

You can also override and use default/global settings with other packages with this same approach, when applicable and if the linter supports it.  Another good example is with the [SublimeLinter-jshint plugin](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint#settings).

Comment: Thanks. My main misunderstanding was how to translate the CLI to sublimelinter configuration